# Android exception when the function onClick bean activate

Tags: android, crash

have a button that when i press is finishing the Activity,but the thing going wrong an i am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: "Could not find a method false(View) in the activity class
```

what could be the reason of this exception?

Thanks for Helping

Comment: Seems like you are trying to call a method that doesn't exist. Can you show some code?

Comment: This question is extremely vague. If my answer below doesn't work for you, try posting some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are declaring an `android:onClick` listener in your layout xml file, but that method cannot be called.

Make sure that your method (which is appearently called `false`):

- exists in your `Activity` class
- is `public`
- takes exactly one argument of type `View`